# how to display differenet youtube videos in one iframe

Tags: iframe, youtube

```html
<p><a class="one" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fr55ie7LE50" target="iframe_a">Link Text</a></p>
<iframe name="iframe_a" id="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

how to make a few button that each button will play a different YouTube video in one same iframe in the page?
like the example I've added I want to make a few more links that each link will play another video from youtube in the same iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more links that look like button using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fr55ie7LE50?autoplay=1" target="iframe_a" role="button">Play video1</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7LEmer7wwHI?autoplay=1" target="iframe_a" role="button">Play video2</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T4ZE2KtoFzs?autoplay=1" target="iframe_a" role="button">Play video3</a>
</p>
<iframe name="iframe_a" id="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/o2vmfyxt/1/)

Comment: The current snippet only creates an iFrame and does not set any video as default.. Only by clicking a button does a video start.. How can I make one of these default video?